# Why does this code result in the divs side by side rather than in a vertical column?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float two divs on the right side of the page so that they stack:

```html
<div style=" float: right;">
    <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: #2835d0;; color: white; border-radius: 10px;">
        test1
    </div>
</div>


<div style=" float: right;">
    <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: #2835d0;; color: white; border-radius: 10px;">
        test2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When using float, the `<div>` elements will be "shrink-wrapped", therefore leaving sufficient horizontal space for the next float element to come up next to it.

Comment: As @Terry said, two divs will locate same position. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```css
.text-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-container">
    <div>
        <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: #2835d0;; color: white; border-radius: 10px;">
            test1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: #2835d0;; color: white; border-radius: 10px;">
            test2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcome. I think you can check my answer is right. ;) Thank you.

Comment: yes, the "run code snippet" is really useful!

Comment: I mean that you can approve my answer. Thank you. ;)

Comment: ok, I clicked the up arrow, hopefully that approved it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am sorry for disturb you. I meant that I want you to click check mark bellow the down arrow of vote numbers. If you click that, you can see the check mark changes its color to green. It means that my answer helped your question. And then      click up arrow again. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't know how to do, I think you can see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers